# PnP js call returns "Item does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, 2016, pnpjs

I'm running a small code to upload file in a SharePoint 2016 document library and to change a metadata.

Sometimes (but really often) my code returns error "Error making HttpClient request in queryable [404] Not Found" with the message "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

This is my code:

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/ConfigDL").files.add(fileOgg.name, fileOgg, true).then(function (data) {
    var RelativeUrls="/sites/mysite/ConfigDL/"+fileOgg.name;
    //Retrive Document which is uploaded. Start
    pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(RelativeUrls).getItem().then(item => {
        //update start Below Call to Doc List will update the Row baseed on Item.ID
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ConfigDL").items.getById(item.ID).update({
            Number: ""+number+""
        }).then(r => {
            alert(file.name + " upload successfully!");
        });//update end
    }); //Retrive Doc Info End
}); //Upload Document End
```

I can't get why this error happens randomly and what's wrong with my code. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly due the async nature of the HTTP requests.

To upload the file and then set it properties correctly, you can do so as below:

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/ConfigDL").files.add(fileOgg.name, fileOgg, true).then(f => {

    f.file.getItem().then(item => {
        //update start Below Call to Doc List will update the Row baseed on Item.ID
        item.update({
            Number: ""+number+""
        }).then(r => {
            alert(fileOgg.name + " upload successfully!");
        });//update end
    }); //Retrive Doc Info End
}); //Upload Document End
```

You can refer the documentation [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files)

Approach 2:

```
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/ConfigDL").files.add(fileOgg.name, fileOgg, true).then(f => {

      f.file.listItemAllFields.get(new ODataDefaultParser(), {
                  headers: {
                      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                  }
              }).then(function (item) {
                  item.update({
                    Number: ""+number+""
                  });
              });
          });
```

Comment: This is my updated code https://jsfiddle.net/Pepozzo/co69z5e2/1/ and still returning same error.

Comment: can you try with approach 2 ? I have added no-cache headers

Comment: This second approach returns "ODataDefaultParser is not defined"